# DOM vs. ElementTree vs Xpath

Tags: xml, dom, xpath, elementtree

I am well aware that this question has been asked plenty of times before but so much has happened with XPath and similar that I figured it might be time to do so again.

In my thesis I will attempt to implement a program to perform Three-way merge of slx files (Matlab Simulink).
What seems to be the easiest way to do this is to manipulate the xml files building the slx file.

I can't seem to find any fairly recent discussion on DOM vs XPath vs ElementTree (Python), most questions seem to be 3-5 years old.

As far as I have understood from older posts is that DOM is more flexible and creates a DOM object which contains all the nodes and allow me to manipulate the file (seems very useful).
XPath is more suited for choosing particular values or relationships within the tree since its faster and uses less memory.
ElementTree is something I just came across browsing through the questions here and I can't seem to figure out which of these three will be of most use.

Comment: A comparison of "DOM vs XPath vs ElementTree" is weird, because only DOM and ElementTree are _models_ to represent XML documents. XPath is a _query language_ (that by the way usually uses XDM as its data model). Tell us more about your project: What language do you use, Python? Do you manipulate only XML files or also other types of data? Are you concerned about performance? About memory usage? Is this intended to run on the web or is it a local setup?

Comment: For easiness: Use **XQuery**. On xml conferences it is consensus that DOM should never been used, except for implementing a XPath/etc. library. XPath is great for selecting, but cannot manipulate the document. XQuery is XPath with expressions to  manipulate it. (I do not know ElementTree, sounds like DOM) (Some people prefer XSLT to XQuery, but I do not like it. XSLT is nothing like XPath)

Comment: I am trying to implement a three-way mergetool for simulink slx files. This is a compressed format containing mostly xml files. I have not yet decided what language to use but I'm most familiar with Java. What I like about DOM is that it seems very intuitive and I can relate the algorithms in a way I can't with SAX. However I have 0 prior knowledge in any of these which is why I'm confused getting into all this.